# How to set up Mac for multiple user remote access log in and a shared network drive?

Tags: macos, network, security, remote-desktop

I have users who want to share a highpowered mac in a lab. It has a decent processor and a ton of RAM. They want to be able to remotely access this mac from both PC/Mac just like a user would be able to do for Windows using remote desktop. It is possible that two or more users (but no more than 4) would want to access this machine at the same time. It should have enough ram to handle this. They also want a drive on this mac that they can all share on their lab network.

Obviously, they want this to be as secure as possible. I am primarily a windows user, so any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: would this work for you https://support.apple.com/en-bn/HT204618

Comment: Would the users need their own home directory on this Mac or simply sharing access?

Comment: @StuartH Good question, I was assuming sharing access only.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest using Teamviewer software (https://www.teamviewer.com/en/index.aspx) and install on all computers wishing to access the Mac as well as the Mac itself - this has worked very well for me in the past, and as a bonus they will be able to access the Mac from mobile devices etc. if the need arises.